# CSS nav button scrolling not working on mobile

Tags: html, css

Having trouble with a CSS navigation menu button on mobile. The content doesn't scroll on mobile/touch, which it needs to as it would be too long due to multiple  links. Any help, please?

```
.dropbtn {
  border: #3eab37 solid 2px;
  color: white;
  /*padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;*/
  font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 165px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap; /* [1] */
  overflow-x: auto; /* [2] */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* [3] */
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 254px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #3eab37;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g0tapbdk/2/

Thank you!

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g0tapbdk/2/ thank you!

Comment: I tested it on iOS and the menu scrolled as expected. The button is a little buggy because its triggered by a hover effect. But, seems to work. What are you testing it on?

Comment: Testing it the live page with the rest of my site. it's on a 100vh overlay, could this be connected? 
Also it's on a scrollable page site. 

Thanks

Comment: You can test different `body` overflow properties in combination with your menu properties

Comment: Dropdowns are not really user-friendly for mobile screens. It is hard to scroll on such small area on a mobile device. [Read more here](https://medium.com/@kollinz/dropdown-alternatives-for-better-mobile-forms-53e40d641b53)